# Having some WARNINGS that i can not figure why while running a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I'm currently working on a team project. Working with Maven, JPA, EclipseLink and H2. We, all the team members, have the same versions of Java, Maven, used frameworks, etc. However, I'm the only one having some WARNINGS that i can not figure why. I have already deleted the respective .m2 folders and cloned the project again, but that didn't resolve my problem. This are the warnings that appear:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1133